# Issue with DateTime after migration from jdk6 to jdk8

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-6

I found out this annoying exception after migration from jdk1.6 to jdk1.8. For 1.6 it works fine, but 1.8 returns null:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JodaTest {


    public static final String strDate = "Nov 2 2010 12:27AM";
    private static final String ISSUED_DATE_PATTERN = "MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa";
    private static final DateTimeZone TIMEZONE = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago");
    private static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(ISSUED_DATE_PATTERN).withZone(TIMEZONE);

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(strDate); //Exception - Invalid format
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```

output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Nov 2 2010 12:27AM"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
    at com.nxsystems.processor.kokard.client.JodaTest.testName(JodaTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

local US

TimeZone +11

JAVA_HOME=c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\

What other surprises I can expect with DdateTime after migration?

Comment: Works fine for me, on both 1.6 and 1.8. You should remove that `catch` block, though, that's a bad way of handling errors. If you're getting `null` because of a bad argument, then your answer is in that exception - don't just throw it away

Comment: Which version of Joda time?

Comment: joda-time.2.6. Isn't it a part of jdk since java8?

Comment: @DmitriiBorovoi Joda-Time is NOT a part of Java-8 which contains a new date-time-library in java.time-package (although guided by the same author). And the author S. Colebourne himself recommends migration to java.time-library, not keeping Joda-Time (therefore I see Joda-Times-future to be doomed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify locale explicitly

```
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.withLocale(new Locale("en_EN")).parseDateTime(strDate);
```

otherwise it doesn't work on jdk>=7

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is, as I can't reproduce it here.  I suspect it's the formatter here:

```
private static final String ISSUED_DATE_PATTERN = "MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa";
```

You might need to use a single `'d'` and `'a'` for day of month and AM/PM.

Alternatively, the `java.time.*` API in Java 8 will do what you need:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JavaTimeTest {

    public static final String strDate = "Nov 2 2010 12:27AM";
    private static final String ISSUED_DATE_PATTERN = "MMM d yyyy hh:mma";
    private static final ZoneId TIMEZONE = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
    private static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISSUED_DATE_PATTERN);

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
      LocalDateTime localDateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parse(strDate, LocalDateTime::from);
      ZonedDateTime dateTime = localDateTime.atZone(TIMEZONE);
      System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```